# Apache2 setup macOS Monterey error Forbidden

Tags: macos, apache, web-config, apache2, macos-monterey

I'm looking for a way to use multiple DocumentRoots on the local Apache server of MacOs Monterey. localhost works very well but for the other locations I have an error "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource."

I tried to use VirtualHost but it doesn't work

httpd.conf

```
ServerName localhost:80

#
# Deny access to the entirety of your server's filesystem. You must
# explicitly permit access to web content directories in other 
# <Directory> blocks below.
#
<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

#
# DocumentRoot: The directory out of which you will serve your
# documents. By default, all requests are taken from this directory, but
# symbolic links and aliases may be used to point to other locations.
#
DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents">
    Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
    MultiviewsMatch Any
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>


<Directory "/Library/WebServer/CGI-Executables">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>


Include /private/etc/apache2/other/*.conf
```

extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

```
# Virtual Hosts

Listen 80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Library/WebServer/Documents"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/IUT/S3/Prog-Web-Serveur"
    ServerName iut.local
#    ServerAlias iut
    ErrorLog "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/IUT/S3/Prog-Web-Serveur/crash_log/Error"
    CustomLog "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/IUT/S3/Prog-Web-Serveur/crash_log/Custom" common
    <Directory "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/IUT/S3/Prog-Web-Serveur">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin example@example.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/Perso/EclypseGames/Local_Dev"
    ServerName eclypsegames.local
    ErrorLog "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/Perso/EclypseGames/Local_Dev/crash_log/Error"
    CustomLog "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/Perso/EclypseGames/Local_Dev/crash_log/Custom" common
    <Directory "/Users/TooikLeChevalier/Documents/Perso/EclypseGames/Local_Dev"> 
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

../hosts

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1       iut.local
127.0.0.1       eclypsegames.local
```

I have enclosed with you all the documents that could be useful in solving my problem.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Consider shortening your configuration files to the relevant minimum: There's a _humongous_ amount of irrelevant comments in there. You want to make it easy for people to answer, not have us wade through heaps of irrelevant stuff. Please read [ask], take the [tour] and edit your question with a [mcve]

Comment: Where is `extra/httpd-vhosts.conf` being included? "...but it doesn't work" - Please explain what you mean exactly by "doesn't work"? Do you get an error? Does the request resolve? What URL are you requesting? etc.

Comment: @MrWhite when I said "I tried to use VirtualHost but it doesn't work" it's in reference at the text juste above, so, the error "Forbidden You don't have permission to access this resource."